# tar command not excluding files properly

Tags: linux, unix

While running a tar command today, I was trying to exclude a directory of files inside of the file system.  I ran this command -

`tar --exclude='./my/directory/here' -zcvf backup.tar.gz docroot/`

However, when it was tar'ing the directory, it was still including files from the "here".  How can I get it to exclude the files properly?

Mine is not working correctly - see demo -

```
$ sudo tar --exclude='./jsmith/testDirectory/' -zcvf backup.tar.gz ./jsmith/
[sudo] password for jsmith:
./jsmith/
./jsmith/.bash_logout
./jsmith/backup2015-9-8.sql.gz
./jsmith/.mysql_history
./jsmith/.bashrc
./jsmith/testDirectory/
./jsmith/testDirectory/test4.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/test2.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/test6.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/deploy/
./jsmith/testDirectory/test8.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/tets12.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/test1.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/test7.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/test9.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/test11.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/test10.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/test3.sh
./jsmith/testDirectory/test5.sh
./jsmith/.viminfo
./jsmith/.drush/
./jsmith/.drush/cache/
./jsmith/.drush/cache/usage/
./jsmith/.drush/cache/default/
```

Comment: BTW, in the future, your demonstrations / reproducers should also create all the files they need to have the output you show, so readers have everything they need to recreate the problem and test their proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming needs to be consistent!

```
tar --exclude='./my/directory/here' -zcvf backup.tar.gz docroot/
```

...should be, instead, something like:

```
tar --exclude='docroot/my/directory/here' -zcvf backup.tar.gz docroot/
```

...which is to say: If you don't use a leading `./` in the name of the files to be included in the tarball, you can't use a leading `./` in the name of the files to exclude. (The inverse applies as well: If you *did* use `./docroot` in the filename, you would need to use it in the exclude pattern as well).

---

Observe:

```
$ mkdir -p docroot/my/directory/here/content docroot/other/content
$ tar --exclude='./docroot/my/directory/here/' -zcvf backup.tar ./docroot/
a ./docroot
a ./docroot/my
a ./docroot/other
a ./docroot/other/content
a ./docroot/my/directory
```

Notably, while `my/directory` is present, `my/directory/here` is not, and neither is `my/directory/here/content`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, if I type the command tar --exclude='./docroot/my/directory/here/' -zcvf backup.tar ./docroot/ it still includes the files from the "here" directory

Comment: @Proximus, see the demonstrator amended to the answer, showing this working as designed.

Comment: @Proximus, ...if you have continued issues, I'd suggest adding a tested reproducer to your question so other people can see them (See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added a demo to my original question showing it not working correctly.

Comment: I can confirm the proposed answer, simply cut and pasted to a Debian Jessie Linux system does not work, viz:
`$ mkdir -p docroot/my/directory/here/content docroot/other/content
$ tar --exclude='./docroot/my/directory/here/' -zcvf backup.tar ./docroot/
./docroot/
./docroot/other/
./docroot/other/content/
./docroot/my/
./docroot/my/directory/
./docroot/my/directory/here/
./docroot/my/directory/here/content/
$`

Comment: However, remove the trailing slashes and all works as required:
`$ mkdir -p docroot/my/directory/here/content docroot/other/content  
$ tar --exclude='./docroot/my/directory/here' -zcvf backup.tar ./docroot  
./docroot/  
./docroot/other/  
./docroot/other/content/  
./docroot/my/  
./docroot/my/directory/  
$`

(Sorry about poor formatting, and weird that StackOverflow doesn't allow me to paste this all as one comment - too long!)

Comment: You didn't have a trailing slash in the exclude in your original question, so until you added a working reproducer, how could anyone have possibly found the problem? (This is part of why MCVEs are so important).